# How to get different answers on output?

Tags: python

I'm making a Python program to generate Google Meet codes (not planning to use them and merely for an experiment to see if they're valid, but when executed and asked how many codes the user wants, it just returns the same one multiple times.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

letters = ''
letters2 = ''
letters3 = ''
def code_gen():
    quantity = int(input('How many codes do you want?'))
for c in range(3):
    letters += random.choice(chars)
for c in range(4):
    letters2 += random.choice(chars)
for c in range(3):
    letters3 += random.choice(chars)

code = letters + '-' + letters2 + '-' + letters3

for i in range(quantity):
    print('Your code is', code)
j = input('Would you like to do it again?')
return j

while True:
    i = code_gen()
    if i =='yes' or i=='y':
        code_gen()
        elif i=='no' or i=='n':
            break
        else:
            print('Input not valid.')
            break
```

And I'm also getting a syntax error on the elif line, but I don't know why.

Comment: Indentation does not match with the `if` above.

Comment: Because you generate `code` only **once**, while you print the same `code` value `quantity` times

Comment: You need to fix your indentation in your post, as written code_gen doesn't do anything useful at all. Copy your code into your post, highlight it, and press ctrl + k

Comment: @Sayse I'm not quite understanding your comment, sorry. Could you explain it?

Comment: `code_gen` is a function that just takes an input then does nothing with it, you need to format your post correctly.

Comment: The indentation of your code isn't correct. Maybe you made an error while posting it here. The code will not run as it is. For example `for i in range(quantity):` won't work because `quantity` is not known in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Working code as per your requirement

```py
import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


def code_gen():
    quantity = int(input('How many codes do you want?'))
    for _ in range(quantity):
        letters = ''
        letters2 = ''
        letters3 = ''
        for c in range(3):
            letters += random.choice(chars)
        for c in range(4):
            letters2 += random.choice(chars)
        for c in range(3):
            letters3 += random.choice(chars)

        code = letters + '-' + letters2 + '-' + letters3

        print('Your code is', code)
    j = input('Would you like to do it again?')
    return j


while True:
    i = code_gen()
    if i == 'yes' or i == 'y':
        code_gen()
    elif i == 'no' or i == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print('Input not valid.')
        break
```